# Getting Error while Launching my App on Emulator

Tags: android

i am also getting this error how can i fix it?

[image]

> "Unexpected error while executing: am start -n "com.example.project/com.example.project.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER Error while Launching activity"

I am getting this error when i run my application on emulator

here is the code of menifest file:

```
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
</application>
```

Comment: Show your Manifest file code.

Comment: Please [edit] your post and post full stack trace/error log

Comment: post Manifest file code please

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest file code.

Answer (score 0):

```
        <activity
            android:name="MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
```

check this code and compare this with your manifest. Hope it helps you